# Finding the basis of a space with a given condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let

$W = \begin{Bmatrix}(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x + 2y + 3z = 0\end{Bmatrix}$

$B = \begin{Bmatrix}(1,1,-1),(0,3,2),(3,0,1)\end{Bmatrix}$

I need to get to a situation where $Span(B) = W$, but $B$ isn't a basis for $W$.

However, I find that $B$ is linearly independent, So if $Span(B) = W$ doesn't that mean that it's the basis?

This is how I found the $W$:

$\begin{matrix}
x = -2y -3z
\\
\begin{pmatrix}-3y-2z\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow y\begin{pmatrix}-3\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}, z\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}$

I can't wrap my head around this, because if $Span(B) = W$ and $B$ is linearly independent than $dim(B) = dim(W)$ but this clrealy isn't the case here.

Thanks

Comment: That is correct, since $B$ is LI it can not span a two dimensional subspace.